# Can I automatically Record in a google sheet column , the timings that other google sheets have been edited by others?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have over 50 sheets in google docs that I have shared with many people. Can I automate the recording and entry of time that each person updates the sheet in a particular column in another sheet ? Notifications is fine but instead of manually entering the timing each person updates the sheet , can it be automated ?

P.S.1) If yes , can I also get the ID of the person who has edited the sheet in the next column to timing ?

P.S.2) If yes again , is it possible to get a list of updates i.e 1 user making 5 edits will have 5 different timing and another column which picks the last updated time .

This would universally save me time and help me keep a tab on my users ( employees ) and also give then a chance to improve .

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach an onEdit event handler.

You can only get user account info if you have a Google Apps for Work account.

You may want to check answer to this question: [how to attach onChange cell value event/script to google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768532/how-to-attach-onchange-cell-value-event-script-to-google-sheet)

-- just opinion --

Google Drive/Apps for Work is built for collaboration, and such micro-management (having to see every single edit) kind of defeat its very own purpose. My suggestion is just use the built-in revision tracker, which gives you a more compact (and efficient, management-wise) view of the edits. You can [get Google drive activity using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656584/get-google-drive-activity-using-google-apps-script) to send your manager a periodic update on what files were changed so they can check on those.